# CakePHPのquery()でlimitにバインド変数を使いたい

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP2.6を使用しています。

query()で実行するSQLにlimit句がありその値をバインド変数で可変にしたいと考えています。

```
limit :limit
```

とし、

```
$this->query($sql, ['limit' => 1], false);
```

と値をセットして実行するとlimit句に文字列の1が入ってしまいエラーとなります。

PDOならbindValueの引数にPDO::PARAM_INTを設定して解消出来るようですが
CakephpだとDboSource::_execute()内でexecute()が実行されるまでにそれが設定出来るような箇所は無いように見えます。

CakePHPでlimit句に値を指定する方法はあるのでしょうか

追記
?を使った方法でも同様のエラーとなります。

```
LIMIT ?
```

```
$this->query($sql, [1], false);
```

またエラーメッセージは以下のとおりです。

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 12

Comment: [意外と知られていない？ queryメソッドで値をbindできるってこと](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/cakephper/20090417/1239939705)

Comment: @argus その記事は確認済みなのですがargusさんはそれで動いてます？バージョン違いなのか私の環境では同じエラーとなります。

Comment: すみません、この記事が出た直後(2009年頃)にCakePHP 1.x で試した時は期待通りに動いていましたが、、`?` を使う方法でもエラーになるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、?でも同様です。エラーメッセージも含めて質問に追加しておきます。

Comment: 実際に CakePHP で動作確認をしていないので、間違っていたらごめんなさいですが、`query()` を実行する前に `$this->getConnection()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` を実行してみて下さい。PDO + MySQL だけの環境で試した場合、これで問題のエラーが発生しなくなります(正常終了します)。

Comment: 試してみたところ上手くlimitが効くようになりました。(getConnection前にgetDataSource()を入れる必要がありました)
ただ(ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=falseの挙動としては正しいと思うのですが)受け取る結果がDBの設定に沿った型で返るためこのまま使うのは悩ましいところです。
とはいえDBO周りの設定も触れそうだという事が分かりましたのでこの辺細かく見ていこうと思います。
ありがとうございました！